# Can I send money to an EOS public key?

Tags: accounts, account-name, account-creation

I run a dApp and I want my users to be able to send transactions client-side. One of the best parts about other blockchains is that I can just use a traditional pubKey to send money.

I was wondering if there is any way to send money to an EOS pubkey without an account name. If yes, I was wondering if there are any `testnet` faucets that support sending EOS to a pubkey without an account name.

EOS is great software with its RAM and CPU markets. But if I have to create a new account for each of my users to send a transaction client-side, then this is a huge design flaw.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send money to a public key, because the same public key can be used for many accounts, and the code wouldn't know which account should receive the money. This is the same on any eos.io based blockchain.

You can keep a record in one of your tables about which public key has what money associated with it, and then only send money to an account when they ask for it.

Otherwise, you'd have to set up an account for each of your users, at a cost of approximately 0.7 EOS in RAM.

Comment: DUDE...... EOS is great tech. It has the RAM and CPU markets which are huge pluses over other blockchains. I am also a fan of dPOS, although with more nodes and a different way of selecting them. Anyway, this is one feature I CANNOT accept. The whole point is blockchain is to PREVENT  centralized database for storing money! That's how Mt.Gox, LibertyMoney, and everything that came before EOS failed!! But okay, I understand... thanks... I have to decide if I will continue to support EOS in my dApp.

Comment: Perhaps there is another way to achieve what you want. Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve? "Sending transactions client-side" is a bit vague for me to understand

Comment: Okay nevermind. The fact that you have to pay EOS to create an account means i will be discluding EOS from my app for new users. Really really disappointing.

Comment: Check this out: Free accounts on EOS courtesy of LiquidApps https://medium.com/@liquidapps/all-aboard-the-eos-train-its-free-dbc00d9b21f

Comment: That is amazing.